# Excel Power Query; Expand table into columns

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have two tables that I'd like to merge, but I can't quite get the merge to work the way I'd like it to. The first is a list of days and some data, the second is a ranking of items sold that day along with the number sold, etc. I'd like to get the top 'x' items added as columns to my daily data. I got the merge to work, and so now I have a column that says 'table.' However if I expand the table, each item turns into its own row. Instead I'd like table item 2 to repeat all of its columns with a postfix.

| date | total_sales | items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/21 | $50000 | table |
| 1/2/21 | $40000 | table |

| date | total_sales | items_1 | units_1 | items_2 | units_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/21 | $50000 | pens | 15 | pencils | 10 |
| 1/2/21 | $40000 | erasers | 35 | pens | 5 |

etc.

I can do this with visual basic but I don't think that's the best way to go about it. Thanks for your help! Also, is there a specific term for this operation that I could have searched for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose your second table looks like this:

[image: Data table]

First, let's group by date where for each group we sort and index the subtable. (This is the hardest step.)

[image: Group by date]

Once we have the index for each group, expand that column back so we're back to the start except with the new index column.

[image: Original plus index]

From here, you can filter the index to get only the top N and then unpivot the [items] and [units] columns.

[image: Unpivot]

Merge the [index] and [Attribute]

[image: Merge columns]

and then pivot on [Merged]

[image: Pivot]

Ta da! Now your data is shaped so that you can easily merge it with the first table.

---

Here's the full code for this example. (You can paste this into the Advanced Editor and look through Applied Steps.)

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMtQ31DcyMDJU0lEqSM0rBlKGpkqxOugSyZk5YDkDqJwRTC61KLE4tQgkZ2yKLgc1EMM8hB5sWqBWGSnFxgIA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [date = _t, items = _t, units = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"date", type date}, {"items", type text}, {"units", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"date"}, {{"indexed", each Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.Buffer(Table.Sort(_, {{"units", Order.Descending}})), "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type), type table}}),
    #"Expanded indexed" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "indexed", {"items", "units", "Index"}, {"items", "units", "Index"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded indexed", each [Index] < 3),
    #"Unpivoted Columns1" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Filtered Rows", {"date", "Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Columns1", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Attribute", "Index"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("_", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Pivoted Column1" = Table.Pivot(#"Merged Columns", List.Distinct(#"Merged Columns"[Merged]), "Merged", "Value"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Pivoted Column1",{{"items_1", type text}, {"units_1", Int64.Type}, {"items_2", type text}, {"units_2", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

The only place I'm doing special M language magic (not just clicking stuff in the GUI) is this step which I created by applying a couple of steps to one of the sub-tables and pasting the GUI-generated code back into the group by step (plus Table.Buffer wrapper to make sure the sorting "sticks").

```
#"Grouped Rows" =
    Table.Group(
        #"Changed Type",
        {"date"},
        {
            {"indexed", each
                Table.AddIndexColumn(
                    Table.Buffer(
                        Table.Sort(_, {{"units", Order.Descending}})
                    ),
                    "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type
                ), type table
            }
        }
    ),
```